# Adding single NSLayoutConstraint gives "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a custom cell containing some UILabels and UIImageviews. When i set constraints of an UIImage (reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet), it is positioned in the lower right corner of the cell as expected.

When setting a LeftAnchor UIConstraint for the UILabel reportCellDateTimeOutlet to position the label 20pts left of the cellborder i get a constraint conflict i not yet understand. What is a good way to approach this conflict?

```
2016-05-10 22:24:16.331 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e7f9b0 UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e79910 UILabel:0x7fc241e9f580'23 hours ago'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e8da20 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e9f580'23 hours ago'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e88e90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e88f30 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243769da0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e88e90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-10 22:24:16.350 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24375c4a0 UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc2435e27a0 UILabel:0x7fc241e38520'35 minutes ago'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc2435464a0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e38520'35 minutes ago'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243507050 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc2434d4bc0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e84350 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243507050 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-10 22:24:16.351 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e257c0 UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e01ab0 UILabel:0x7fc241e24e40'just now'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24373e310 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e24e40'just now'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e96a80 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e95e10 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243189f30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e96a80 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-10 22:24:16.363 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e7f9b0 UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e79910 UILabel:0x7fc241e9f580'23 hours ago'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e90310 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e9f580'23 hours ago'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e8fa70 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e8fb10 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243769da0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e8fa70 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-10 22:24:16.364 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24375c4a0 UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc2435e27a0 UILabel:0x7fc241e38520'35 minutes ago'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24345dd10 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e38520'35 minutes ago'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24343ac90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241ee2570 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e84350 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24343ac90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-10 22:24:16.366 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e257c0 UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e01ab0 UILabel:0x7fc241e24e40'just now'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243777090 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e24e40'just now'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241ea1ab0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc2437394d0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243189f30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241ea1ab0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-10 22:24:16.367 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e257c0 UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e01ab0 UILabel:0x7fc241e24e40'just now'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243777090 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e24e40'just now'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241ea1ab0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc2437394d0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243189f30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24282a000'cell'(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241ea1ab0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc2437c1170](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e18880 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-10 22:24:16.368 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24375c4a0 UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc2435e27a0 UILabel:0x7fc241e38520'35 minutes ago'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24345dd10 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e38520'35 minutes ago'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24343ac90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241ee2570 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e84350 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc24299c600'cell'(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc24343ac90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc24354d0d0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc2437901d0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-10 22:24:16.369 homecaremonitor[8024:1968356] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e7f9b0 UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0.right == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'.right - 3>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e79910 UILabel:0x7fc241e9f580'23 hours ago'.left == homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'.left + 20>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e90310 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fc241e9f580'23 hours ago'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e8fa70 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e8fb10 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc243769da0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[homecaremonitor.ReportTableviewCell:0x7fc242bfda00'cell'(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e8fa70 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

[image]

```
class ReportTableviewCell : UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var reportCellSeverityOutlet: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var reportCellDateTimeOutlet: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var reportCellDescriptionOutlet: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var reportCellCustomerLabelOutlet: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var reportCell: UIView!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()

      fadeDescription()

      // Disable autolayout constraints
      reportCell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      // viewed Indicator constraints
      let viewedIndicatorConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.rightAnchor, constant: -3),
        reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomAnchor, constant: -3)

      ]
      NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(viewedIndicatorConstraints)

      let DateTimeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        reportCellDateTimeOutlet.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leftAnchor, constant: 20)
      ]
      NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(DateTimeConstraints)
```

Comment: Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7fc241e8fa70 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(352)-[UIImageView:0x7fc241e9cfa0](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc241e9f9c0 )>.The app is breaking constraint of imageview with height 352 just find it and lower its priority in the attributes inspector

Comment: Couple of points: Add sub views (and therefore constraints) to `contentView` and not to the cell directly. Difficult to debug when you have views in storyboard / IB and add constraints programatically. Do all of it in storyboard or do all of it programatically. Best to use `UIStackView` in your case.

Comment: @Ahmad Ishfaq, thanks found the cause of that one, was an image which was hidden but not removed yet. Also Use Auto Layout and Use Size Classes was selected.

Comment: @user1046037, thanks have gone through a tutorial of UIStackView, will try to use that in a next project. Already created all constraints programmatically. Do not understand the remark not to set constraints to the cell directly. As far as i know i do not set contstrains to the cell directly, only use constraints of the cell to set constraints of UIImage and UIText etc.

Comment: For example you are setting the indicator outlet's right anchor based on self's right anchor (self is the cell). Instead of self use `self.contentView`. To debug this add an symbolic exception break point. Set the symbol name to be `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`. Then run the program, the debugger will stop exactly at the conflicting constraint. In your case there could be multiple conflicting constraints one by one.